# Combine queries into one

Tags: mysql

I would like that as soon as I add a product to the "orders" table, the quantity of the product decreases by 1. I wrote two separate queries to implement this task.

Query to add data to the "orders" table:

```
INSERT INTO orders(id_buyer, id_product, date, status) 
VALUES (2, 8, '2022-05-22', 1);
```

Request to reduce "amount" by one:

```
update products 
set amount = amount - 1, 
amount = amount - 1 
where id in ( select id_product from orders where status = 1);
```

Is it possible to combine these two queries into one?

Comment: You need after insert  trigger  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/

Comment: This is non-recommended way (any problem/fail may make your data incorrect, and this incorrectness won't be detected). You should store the product income and product consumption, and the current amount of the remaining product should be calculated based on these values in the query.

Comment: @Akina I understand that, but I was told to do so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the question (even if this is or not the right way) you can use [AFTER INSERT TRIGGER](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/)

Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_orders_insert AFTER INSERT ON orders 
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE products
     SET amount=amount - 1
   WHERE id = NEW.id_product
   AND NEW.status =1;
```

[Working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51361f5ca142eb54052eb789d2b1a72f)

Comment: i get an error ```ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'orders' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.```

Comment: I'm sorry, everything works, thanks!